# loading ath9k_htc kernel driver fails

Tags: kernel, wifi, kernel-modules

could someone please point me in the right direction to get my external wireless stick (TL-WN722N) working on my Xperia Neo (haida) smartphone?

So far I've done the following:

1. I downloaded LegacyXperia CM11.0 sources and configured the kernel to build the atheros wireless modules. The build of the LX ROM was successful and the ROM runs on my NEO.
2. I copied the atheros firmware (htc_9271.fw) to /system/etc/firmware
3. I insmodded the atheros kernel modules (ath.ko, ath9k_hw.ko, ath9k_common.ko, ath9k_htc.ko)
4. I installed and started Ubuntu Trusty via Linux Deploy
5. Then I connected the wireless dongle (TL-WN722N) to the phone with an powered USB OTG Y cable
6. I forced the usb configuration to overcome the 'insufficient available bus power' message in dmesg (sudo su -c 'echo -n 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/bConfigurationValue')
7. This triggered the firmware to get loaded, but unfortunately the device fails to get initialised, see the dmesg output below.

I would be happy about any help. Thanks heaps!

This is the dmesg output:

```
[  588.347839] usb 1-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware htc_9271.fw requested
[  588.652984] usb 1-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 51272
[  588.889007] ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[  589.107238] ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.3
[  589.107421] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x809c
[  589.107421] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  589.107452] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  589.107452] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52
[  589.107452] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN
[  589.107482] ath: Regpair used: 0x52
[  589.107482] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  589.107604] WARNING: at /home/student/android/system/out/target/product/haida/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/modules/compat_wl12xx/net/wireless/reg.c:1279 wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory+0x130/0x188 [cfg80211]()
[  589.107879] Modules linked in: ath9k_htc ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath mac80211(O) cfg80211(O) compat(O) [last unloaded: wl12xx]
[  589.107940] [<c0012c18>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xe0) from [<c0088b8c>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x4c/0x64)
[  589.107940] [<c0088b8c>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x4c/0x64) from [<c0088bbc>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x18/0x1c)
[  589.107971] [<c0088bbc>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x18/0x1c) from [<bf007ce8>] (wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory+0x130/0x188 [cfg80211])
[  589.108001] [<bf007ce8>] (wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory+0x130/0x188 [cfg80211]) from [<bf023654>] (ath_regd_init+0x110/0x14c [ath])
[  589.108032] [<bf023654>] (ath_regd_init+0x110/0x14c [ath]) from [<bf0f4374>] (ath9k_htc_probe_device+0x574/0x77c [ath9k_htc])
[  589.108062] [<bf0f4374>] (ath9k_htc_probe_device+0x574/0x77c [ath9k_htc]) from [<bf0ec710>] (ath9k_htc_hw_init+0x10/0x2c [ath9k_htc])
[  589.108093] [<bf0ec710>] (ath9k_htc_hw_init+0x10/0x2c [ath9k_htc]) from [<bf0ee110>] (ath9k_hif_usb_firmware_cb+0x17c/0x1a0 [ath9k_htc])
[  589.108123] [<bf0ee110>] (ath9k_hif_usb_firmware_cb+0x17c/0x1a0 [ath9k_htc]) from [<c0319e78>] (request_firmware_work_func+0x84/0xb8)
[  589.108154] [<c0319e78>] (request_firmware_work_func+0x84/0xb8) from [<c009cfe0>] (process_one_work+0x1ec/0x358)
[  589.108184] [<c009cfe0>] (process_one_work+0x1ec/0x358) from [<c009d340>] (worker_thread+0x1c8/0x30c)
[  589.108184] [<c009d340>] (worker_thread+0x1c8/0x30c) from [<c00a18ac>] (kthread+0x80/0x90)
[  589.108215] [<c00a18ac>] (kthread+0x80/0x90) from [<c000e5e0>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
[  589.108215] ---[ end trace e688c0c28db86abf ]---
[  589.108398] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  589.108612] WARNING: at /home/student/android/system/out/target/product/haida/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/modules/compat_wl12xx/net/wireless/core.c:579 wiphy_register+0x4a8/0x518 [cfg80211]()
[  589.108795] Modules linked in: ath9k_htc ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath mac80211(O) cfg80211(O) compat(O) [last unloaded: wl12xx]
[  589.108825] [<c0012c18>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xe0) from [<c0088b8c>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x4c/0x64)
[  589.108856] [<c0088b8c>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x4c/0x64) from [<c0088bbc>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x18/0x1c)
[  589.108856] [<c0088bbc>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x18/0x1c) from [<bf005170>] (wiphy_register+0x4a8/0x518 [cfg80211])
[  589.108917] [<bf005170>] (wiphy_register+0x4a8/0x518 [cfg80211]) from [<bf0295cc>] (ieee80211_register_hw+0x430/0x654 [mac80211])
[  589.108978] [<bf0295cc>] (ieee80211_register_hw+0x430/0x654 [mac80211]) from [<bf0f43dc>] (ath9k_htc_probe_device+0x5dc/0x77c [ath9k_htc])
[  589.108978] [<bf0f43dc>] (ath9k_htc_probe_device+0x5dc/0x77c [ath9k_htc]) from [<bf0ec710>] (ath9k_htc_hw_init+0x10/0x2c [ath9k_htc])
[  589.109039] [<bf0ec710>] (ath9k_htc_hw_init+0x10/0x2c [ath9k_htc]) from [<bf0ee110>] (ath9k_hif_usb_firmware_cb+0x17c/0x1a0 [ath9k_htc])
[  589.109069] [<bf0ee110>] (ath9k_hif_usb_firmware_cb+0x17c/0x1a0 [ath9k_htc]) from [<c0319e78>] (request_firmware_work_func+0x84/0xb8)
[  589.109100] [<c0319e78>] (request_firmware_work_func+0x84/0xb8) from [<c009cfe0>] (process_one_work+0x1ec/0x358)
[  589.109130] [<c009cfe0>] (process_one_work+0x1ec/0x358) from [<c009d340>] (worker_thread+0x1c8/0x30c)
[  589.109130] [<c009d340>] (worker_thread+0x1c8/0x30c) from [<c00a18ac>] (kthread+0x80/0x90)
[  589.109161] [<c00a18ac>] (kthread+0x80/0x90) from [<c000e5e0>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
[  589.109161] ---[ end trace e688c0c28db86ac0 ]---
[  589.110107] Failed to initialize the device
```

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your kernel FIRST, and - if you're not doing so from Git sources, search your package manager for 'linux-firmware' package, you need it. I had similar problems under Android OSE and Ubuntu x86 and arm7hf - all of them were fixed just by doing the things I've mentioned